# Invoking Tensorflow through MATLAB: CUDNN_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED. Error retrieving driver version

Tags: matlab, tensorflow

I have a CNN implemented with Tensorflow that runs perfectly both inside PyCharm IDE and when it is called through the Windows `cmd`. Now I am trying to run the network through MATLAB `system` command by invoking the python script. I am getting the following error:

```
...
2019-02-05 12:37:45.681913: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:373] Could not create cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED
2019-02-05 12:37:45.682038: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:377] Error retrieving driver version: Unimplemented: kernel reported driver version not implemented on Windows
2019-02-05 12:37:45.682192: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:373] Could not create cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED
2019-02-05 12:37:45.682306: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:377] Error retrieving driver version: Unimplemented: kernel reported driver version not implemented on Windows
...
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnknownError: Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning log message was printed above.
```

It is so weird beacause I am launching exactly the same command in the Windows `cmd` or Pycharm IDE and works pefectly, but fails with MATLAB `system` command.

Some idea? It could be something related to conflicts with CUDA/CUDNN in MATLAB?

Thank you very much

Javier.

Comment: Please share the actual command you are giving. MATLAB calls the system, so it should be the same call you write in `cmd` to make it run.

Comment: I am ussing exactly the same command. I've updated the question including the command.

Comment: Unless MATLAB lacks the permissions that python has, or you are running on a different folder and that has influence in the code, this is very non-standard. `system` opens a command window and runs the command in the OS terminal, so there is nothing MATLAB itself is doing. The cmd has no idea that it was called by MATLAB.

Comment: On top of that, it seems that your error can be caused by overloading the GPU memory. Maybe you have already some process running on the GPU when you call it from MATLAB?

Comment: I am quite sure that the installation is correct because I was working with CNNs since a lot of months in PyCharm, cmd, etc, and all the things worked well. Once I have finalized the development of the CNN I tried to run it through MATLAB and thats when the problem comes out, so I think that the problem comes from the way that MATLAB calls the code.

Comment: NOTE: I updated my comment. As I said, MATLAB is not calling the code. MATLAB opens a terminal and tells the OS what to run, the OS is calling the code.

Comment: I know I know, but now I am launching exactly the same command (copy - paste) in a CMD and all works perfect, but if I launch it through MATLAB `system` instruction it crashes.

It could be the Windows user who is launching the code through MATLAB that does not have permissions? or collissions between MATLAB libraries? (don't know if MATLAB has some CUDA inside it), or something similar?

Comment: MATLAB has CUDA inside, for when MATLAB calls CUDA, but this is not the case. Try to change the pyhton code to limit the GPU usage, I still think this is due to requesting more GPU memory than what you can, as some other people with your same problem report on theinternets.

Comment: I tried to limit GPU usage as other users said but the problem is still there. Definelty, it is something related to MALTAB